# Selecting parenthesis in Arabic text

Tags: jquery, arabic

I copied some Arabic text and pasted it on my website. Now I want to select the parentheses in this Arabic text : http://jsfiddle.net/t6Kdc/

```
<span>
    كهيعص ﴿١﴾
</span>
```

```
jQuery(function () {    
    var oldHtml = jQuery('span').html();
    var newHtml = oldHtml.replace("(","<span style='color: red'>﴾</span>");
    jQuery('span').html(newHtml);
});
```

For some reason though, there's no way I can select them. Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not regular parenthesis, those are parenthesis from Arabic script in Unicode. They are represented as:

```
U+FD3E ﴾ arabic ornate left parenthesis
U+FD3F ﴿ arabic ornate right parenthesis
```

(You can see the actual Unicode character rendering at [Arabic script in Unicode on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode#Punctuation_and_ornaments))

To replace them in jQuery, you can do the following:

`var newHtml = oldHtml.replace("\ufd3e","<span style='color: red'>(</span>");` (replace left parenthesis)

`var newHtml = oldHtml.replace("\ufd3f","<span style='color: red'>)</span>");` (replace right parenthesis)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `html`'s function, note that the character that you want to be replaced is not `(`, it's `﴾`.

```
jQuery('span').html(function(i, old){
    return old.replace("﴾", "<span style='color: red'>﴾</span>");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kDWuE/